# Using RegEx to find specific part of a row and replacing original entry

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I'm using the following code to change all rows of a specific column to more compact rows with less information:

```
import re
for row in df1['Description']:
    row = re.findall('(.*)\s', row)
```

The RegEx bit is fine but how do I get the modified data to replace the existing one? I would have thought it was done by row= .... but evidently this just stores the data in a list without replacing. I've looked for another function aside from 'findall' but can't find a relative one.

Comment: What about `re.sub`? Did you check that method?

Comment: Show the original data and how you want it to be? Give an example.

Comment: @stribizhev can't work out how to use that method.. I need three arguments instead of two, which I just can't work out

Comment: The question is absolutely unclear, I cannot help you until you provide input string, expected output, criteria for search and replace. I do not like guessing although I sometimes guess right.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `row` is a temporary variable storing the results of a particular line in the list(?) returned by `df1['Description']`.

To update the original data you will want to refer back to it using the key of the current row which we can pick up using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
import re
for index, row in enumerate(df1['Description']):
    df1['Description'][index] = re.findall('(.*)\s', row)
```

Comment: yes row is storing results in a particular line, only difference in mine is that the column is not the index but a column of many